# не работает сниппет style в js файле - ide vs code

Tags: javascript, сниппет

```
let h1 = document.querySelector('#h1');
h1.style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: а если document.querySelector('h1') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том случаи что вы написали выше - будет работать вот так вот

```
<div id="h1">Text</div>

<script>
  let h1 = document.querySelector('#h1');
  h1.style.color = 'red';
</script>
```

Вероятно, Вы хотели поменять цвет для h1, в таком случаи Ваш код должен быть вот таким:

```
<h1>Text</h1>

<script>
  let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
  h1.style.color = 'red';
</script>
```